# Configure Unity so it does not let window go out of the screen

Tags: x11, monitors, window, unity

Frequently I get my window out of range, I do know I can use super+space but this is annoying, it break my focus, so, there is a way to tell X to not let their windows x+width,y+height position to assume a value out of screens?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: This is not a feature of X11 but of the particular window manager you are using. Which window manager are you using?

Comment: @Kusalananda Unity